# help needed with segmentation error in c code

Tags: c, malloc, segmentation-fault

i am holding data in a buffer,

```
struct buf *bufPtr = malloc((sizeof(struct buf))*(MAX_FILE_SIZE));
```

i then want to write the buffer to a file of size `(sizeof(struct buf))*(MAX_FILE_SIZE)`
the code below will then allow me to open a new file populate it with the contents of the buffer, close the file and free the buffer

```
#define MAX_SIZE_PER_FILE 0x4000000
FILE *fp;
struct buf *bufPtr = malloc((sizeof(struct buf))*(MAX_FILE_SIZE));

k1[0]=0x0000;

k1[1]=0x0000;

while(k1[0] != 0xffff)

{

    while(k1[1] != 0xffff)

    {
                //something different happens in the below line, but has noting to do with segmentation errors
                bufPtr[i].a[1] = k[1]
                //occurs on all variables of the struct

                if( write_count + sizeof(struct buf) >= sizeof(struct buf)*MAX_FILE_SIZE ) {

                     write_count = 0;

                     sprintf( filename, "keys%d", file_idx );

                     file_idx++;

                     fp = fopen(filename, "wb");
                     printf("test1");
                     fwrite(bufPtr, sizeof(struct buf)*(MAX_FILE_SIZE),1,fp);
                     fclose(fp);
                     free(bufPtr);

                  }
                write_count += sizeof(struct buf);
                k1[1]++;

                counter++;

     }
     write_count += sizeof(struct buf);

     k1[1]++;

     i++;
```

}

i get a segmentation fault at a certain point in this code, and i know max_file_size will be bigger, as the struct buf consists of two shorts

```
struct buf{

    unsigned short a[2];

     unsigned short b[2];

};
```

any ideas for me guys

i got this error running it through my mac

```
Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
(gdb)
```

this was on a value within the struct

```
bufPtr[counter].a[0] = a1[0];
```

the line above , occurs before everything else but as it is in another loop, it must be a problem with the amount of memory i am using or allocating

Comment: How did you defined filename?

Comment: it actually writes a file , but when i put a printf before it , the printf does not get called, strangest thing i have ever seen

Comment: @molleman - sometimes the printf() output is not displayed even when it is called because the output is buffered. Just because the text is not displayed does not mean the segfault is occuring before that line.

Comment: yeah i got that ghillis, cheers

Comment: Never, ever call a variable the same as a `struct`. This is just asking for trouble. And you see you got caught in your own trap, when you are doing `sizeof(struct buf)` and `sizeof(buf)`. Tidy up your code would help you most.

Comment: syntax changed , added some more code to show context

Comment: The code as posted just makes no sense. We can't see your definitions or initialization of variables, (i, k, counter, writecount), you haven't marked which line in the code is causing the error, or told us what the values of any of those variables were at the point of the crash. I could go on, but life's too short.

Answer (score 2):

Three things which shouldn't change things, but will make your code MUCH easier for us (and you) to understand and fix.

- NEVER have the same name for variables and types (buf vs. buf), and preferably avoid identifiers that differ only in type. A common idiom is to capitalize types. (`Buf` vs `buf`)
- Format and indent your code nicely
- Use `typedef struct` for struct definitions

Here's an example:

```
typedef struct
{
  unsigned short a[2];
  unsigned short b[2];
} Buffer;

Buffer *buf = malloc(sizeof(Buffer) * MAX_FILE_SIZE);
```

As to what's causing the segfault, it's difficult to say. I'd like to see the `#define` for `MAX_FILE_SIZE`, and more context around where the crash is happening. Your `malloc` looks fine now, but you're not checking to see if it succeeds...

Answer (score 1):

- You never check the return value of [`fopen(3)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/fopen.3.html), which returns `NULL` when it cannot open the file.
- `sizeof( struct buf )` tells you size of the structure, while `sizeof( buf )` gives you size of the `buf` variable, i.e. of a pointer, which is 4 or 8 bytes depending on the platform.

Answer (score 1):

Use sizeof(struct buf) instead.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do: run it under a debugger. What line causes the segfault?

Also, `sizeof(buf)` will always give you 4 on a normal 32-bit machine because you're taking the size of a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule of thumb always error check I/O functions and system calls in general with appropriate error handling code, i.e. return(1). Try running those type of functions in an if statement and handle logging/debugging/exiting within the statement.

Answer (score 0):

try changing the fwrite to:

```
fwrite(buf, sizeof(struct buf), MAX_FILE_SIZE, fp);
```

you allocated struct buf *buf to have memory allocated for MAX_FILE_SIZE number of struct buf data.

The If statement may likely be an issue too; however, I'd need to know what code is around it - is this being done in a loop, etc.